# Invoke-RestMethod PowerShell Google DDNS

Tags: powershell, rest, api, dynamic, dns

I seem to be having a lot of issues with this seemingly basic script to update my IP with Google's DDNS service.

```
#Fetch current IP address
$ipuri = "https://api.ipify.org"
$ip = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $ipuri
#Send fetched IP address to Google Domains through their API
$uri = "https://username:password.google.com/nic/update?hostname=home.domain.com&myip="$ip""
Invoke-RestMethod -Method 'Get' -Uri $uri
```

The first issue is with the $ip variable. It produces no output if I keep the $ip on it but works fine without it (I need it as a variable as I use it later on).

The second issue is with the https://username:password@domains.google.com/nic/update?hostname=home.domain.com&myip="$ip".

It works fine if I dump the exact string into postman (substituting an actual IP address instead of $ip)
but fails to send anything even if I run it with a manually inserted IP (such as https://username:password@domains.google.com/nic/update?hostname=home.domain.com&myip=1.2.3.4) in PowerShell.

P.S. In my actual code I substitute in the correct username and password (as provided by Google) and correct subdomain, domain, top-level domain as it applies to me.

Any thoughts on this?

EDIT:
The updated (and working) code is looks like this:

```
#Fetches current IPv4 address
$ipuri = "https://api.ipify.org"
$ip = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $ipuri
#Stores Google-provided username and password
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "password" -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object Management.Automation.PSCredential ('username', $password)
#Send fetched IP address to Google Domains through their API
$uri = "https://domains.google.com/nic/update?hostname=home.domain.com&myip=$($ip)"
Invoke-RestMethod -Method 'POST' -Uri $uri -Credential $credential
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, that's a neat service, api.ipify.org, I'll have to use that in the future.

Secondly, I think the only issue here is your definition of the `$url`.

The syntax you had before actually throws an error if you try to run the line on its own, error shown here.

```
"https://username:password.google.com/nic/update?hostname=home.domain.com&myip="$ip""
At line:1 char:81
+ ... e:password.google.com/nic/update?hostname=home.domain.com&myip="$ip""
+                                                                     ~~~~~
Unexpected token '$ip""' in expression or statement.
```

In PowerShell you should use string expansion syntax like this, instead of nesting quotes.

```
$uri = "https://username:password.google.com/nic/update?hostname=home.domain.com&myip=$($ip)"
```

### Update

Found the API Docs here https://support.google.com/domains/answer/6147083?hl=en.   They say to provide your username and password using Basic Auth, which makes a base64 encoded string of your credential.  We can do that in PowerShell pretty easily!

You can provide your credentials my using the `Get-Credential` cmdlet to save them then pass them into `Invoke-RestMethod` and adding `-Credential` and `-Authentication` as parameters.  Here is what a completed solution would look like.

```
$ipuri = "https://api.ipify.org"
$ip = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $ipuri
#Send fetched IP address to Google Domains through their API
$myCredential = Get-Credential #you'll be prompted to provide your google username and pwd.  
$uri = "https://domains.google.com/nic/update?hostname=home.domain.com&myip=$($ip)"
Invoke-RestMethod -Method 'POST' -Uri $uri -Credential $myCredential -Authentication Basic
```

Comment: Tried your change in syntax. I receive the following error: Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. At line:4 char:1 + Invoke-RestMethod -Method 'Get' -Uri $uri. Strangely, if I try to Out-File it, the output is completely blank. Is this the case because there is an error or because literally no output was made?

Comment: Can you point to the API Documentation?  It is very, very, *VERY* unlikely that you make an HTTP GET to update your domain info, that's almost always a `PATCH`, `PUT` or `POST`.  The 401 means that at least you're getting close.

Comment: at the bottom of the page under  "Using the API to update your Dynamic DNS record"
[link](https://support.google.com/domains/answer/6147083?hl=en).
I also found it extremely odd that it would allow a GET but the documentation claims (and I verified this through Postman) that a POST or a GET both seem to work.

Comment: Ok, I found the docs and updated my sample.  I have tested it and it appears to work as expected.  Also note that your I fixed the URl, which seemed to be incorrect.

Comment: Tried out your new code, received the following error:
**Invoke-RestMethod : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'AuthenticationBasic'.**
Tried without -AuthenticationBasic and it worked! One last question, if the username and password are not going to change is it possible to somehow hard code them in?

Comment: I missed a space. Parameters and their values in PowerShell always have a space between them, so add one between `-Authentication` and `Basic`.  And its easy to store a credential object, there are dozens of examples on Stack Overflow, just search for 'Store PowerShell credential in script'

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just found another post explaining the saved credentials bit! I'll post the final in my original for anyone else looking. Authentication still throws up an error, even with the space but it works and that's what matters!

Comment: Remember to vote up any post that helped and to accept the answer so others can find it, happy to help you today :)

Comment: Marked as answer but sadly too low level to upvote!